# Corollary of Eberlein Smulian theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

I've read Conway's chapter 4-13.

An Eberlein-Smulian Theorem says that if $X$ is a Banach space and $A \subseteq X$, then TFAE.

1. Each sequence of elements of $A$ has a weakly convergent subsequence
2. Each sequence of elements of $A$ has a weak cluster point
3. The weak closure of $A$ is weakly compact

Next, the author leave me to prove the following corollary:
If $X$ is a Banach space and $A \subseteq X$, then $A$ is weakly compact iff $A\cap M$ is weakly compact for every separable norm closed subspace $M$ of $X$.

The only if part is easy, since $M$ is convex so weak closed, and so $A\cap M$ is weakly compact.

For the if part, ***if we assume $A$ is weakly closed***, then it sufficies to show every sequence in $A$ has a weakly convergent subsequence, by the Eberlein-Smulian Theorem. Now, if $x_n \in A$, then taking $M = \bar{span(x_n)}^{norm}$, we complete the proof.

However, I can't show $A$ is weakly closed. Can anyone help me to prove this ?

Thank you.

**Edit: By the above span - norm closure argument, we can see $A$ is weakly sequentially compact(That is, every sequence in $A$ has a convergent subsequence whose limit is in $A$). Thus it sufficies to show weakly sequentially compact implies weakly closed. (I already know that weakly sequentially 'closed' does not implies weakly closed).

Comment: Why do you need to assume that $A$ is w-closed? You take a sequence $x_n$ in $A$, and define $M$ as you have. Then since $x_n \in A \cap M$ and the latter is w-compact, you can find a weakly convergent subsequence in $A \cap M$ and thus in $A$.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. Then by Eberlein-Smulian, this shows $\bar{A}^{wk}$ is weakly compact. Thus we still need to show $\bar{A}^{wk} = A$, to complete the proof that $A$ is weakly compact.

Comment: The important thing to note is that the limit point lies in $A$. Indeed, since $A \cap M$ is weakly compact, you infer that the w-limit point of $(x_n)$ lies in $A \cap M$. In particular, it lies in $A$.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. Ah, I understand. But we still can't conclude by using the "sequential" limit point argument, because weak topology is not a metric space (or first countable), only where the sequence argument is available. In fact, the topological net argument can be used instead of sequence, but then norm-closure trick to make separable subspace is not possible.